# How could I edit this?

Tags: html

I'm trying to edit wix.com login page but it's very hard, I want this login page for my site cause it looks very nice. I've tried multiple ways to edit it like with `Ctrl+S` but no result. Can someone teach me how to edit this? (Note: I do NOT want to edit their php if that's what you think I mean). Here's the html for their login page: http://pastebin.com/01EYnCvB

Comment: So, you wanna try to edit someone else's minified javascript code?
Good luck then. :)

Comment: No, I just want their login page, I want to edit the html of the page for my site. I will add the needed php files for the page.

Comment: That is Angular App. You need to edit the javascript too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about copyright issues. You can get an idea from their site, but not clone the login page. Add some creativity to it.

You can try any of these:
1) You can make use of developer tools on chrome or firefox. On firefox or chrome, right click on the HTML element that interests you, from the list of options, select inspect element. Then a window will come up showing you the html structure of your site, and the css rules, and many more options to help you out..

2) Another option would be to view page source, and the click on the css file. But I think the previous method is easier.

These methods can help you get the css of their login page, but you need some idea of javascript to make it function like their login page.
There could be other methods out there, but I think this should do the trick.